# Get confused about the `command` option in some ConTeX \setup*

Tags: macros, context, parameters

Since I switched to ConTeXt from plain TeX, I always get confused about macros in it. Now it is the command option in `\setup*` of ConTeXt.

In ConTeXt, some macros, like `\setuphead`, `\setuplist`, have some options which contain the `command=\...#1#2` that we can define some `\def\...` to assign. for example, the `\setuphead`:

```
    \setuphead [1][2]
      1. SECTION
      2. ...
         command = \...#1#2
         ...
```

An example using this is given in page 209 of the ConTeXt manual

```
    {\hbox to \hsize
       {\hfill
        \framed[height=1cm, width=2cm, align=left]{#1}%
        \framed[height=1cm, width=4cm, align=right]{#2}}}
```

here, it is obviously that `#1` is the `headnumber` and `#2` the `title`. At the same time, some commands don't have the examples like this, so, how can I get the information about what meaning the parameters (#1, #2, and so on) refer to?

Comment: Empirically works best ;) But almost always, the arguments are to-be-typeset text arguments (as opposed to e.g. setups or variables) and generally, they are in the expected order: the text object that you expect to be the leftmost in the typeset output tends to be #1, next is #2, et cetera.

Comment: Yeah, Taco, although some details are not presented in ConTeXt manual, the guess fits the experiments well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empirically works best ;)

But almost always, the arguments are to-be-typeset text arguments (as opposed to e.g. setups or variables) and generally, they are in the expected order: the text object that you expect to be the leftmost in the typeset output tends to be #1, next is #2, et cetera.